# Looping through filter result yield bogus empty HTML attributes

Tags: php, symfony, functional-testing

I've got this in my functional test:

```
$questionnaires = [4, 5];
$boxes = $this->crawler->filter('#' . CustomerQuestionnairesType::BLOCK_PREFIX . '_questionnaires input[type=checkbox]');
$count = $boxes->count();
$this->assertGreaterThan(0, $count, "Couldn't find questionnaire check boxes");

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $box = $boxes->getNode($i);
    $value = $box->getAttribute('value');
    $checked = $box->getAttribute('checked');
    $in_array = in_array($value, $questionnaires);
    echo ";test $i: with value=$value checked=" . $checked . " should be=$in_array ". $box->getAttribute('id')."\n";
    $this->assertEquals($in_array ? 'checked' : '', $checked, "Invalid questionnaire map");
}
```

Here's the HTML (saved from `$client->getResponse()->getContent()`):

```
<div id="mobilformbundle_customer_questionnaires_questionnaires">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label class=""><input checked="checked" id="mobilformbundle_customer_questionnaires_questionnaires_4" name="mobilformbundle_customer_questionnaires[questionnaires][]"
         type="checkbox" value="4"> questionnaire1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label class=""><input checked="checked" id="mobilformbundle_customer_questionnaires_questionnaires_5" name="mobilformbundle_customer_questionnaires[questionnaires][]"
         type="checkbox" value="5"> questionnaire2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label class=""><input checked="checked" id="mobilformbundle_customer_questionnaires_questionnaires_6" name="mobilformbundle_customer_questionnaires[questionnaires][]"
         type="checkbox" value="6"> questionnaire3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label class=""><input id="mobilformbundle_customer_questionnaires_questionnaires_10" name="mobilformbundle_customer_questionnaires[questionnaires][]"
         type="checkbox" value="10"> generic questionnaire</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the first 3 boxes are checked (HTML attribute `checked` having the value `checked`).

Here's the output of my test:

```
;test 0: with value=4 checked=checked should be=1 mobilformbundle_customer_questionnaires_questionnaires_4
;test 1: with value=5 checked= should be=1 mobilformbundle_customer_questionnaires_questionnaires_5

Expected :'checked'
Actual   :''
```

I don't understand why the `$checked` PHP variable is empty. It should contain `checked`.

Is there some kind of error in my loop?

Comment: Loop looks good to me. Slightly bizarre eh?

Answer (score 0):

The `$this->crawler` object was from a previous request.

I replaced this (the statement just above the code block I pasted):

```
$this->client->submit($form, $formData);
```

with:

```
$this->crawler = $this->client->submit($form, $formData);
```

and it worked:

```
;test 0: with value=4 checked=checked should be=1 mobilformbundle_customer_questionnaires_questionnaires_4
;test 1: with value=5 checked=checked should be=1 mobilformbundle_customer_questionnaires_questionnaires_5
;test 2: with value=6 checked=checked should be= mobilformbundle_customer_questionnaires_questionnaires_6
;test 3: with value=10 checked= should be= mobilformbundle_customer_questionnaires_questionnaires_10
```

Test passed!

Sorry for the dumb question. Feel free to close-vote it.